# Is there an alternative in Android Java for Message sendToTarget to access View in inner class of an activity?

Tags: java, android

i have an activity where i have a text view. I am also using an sdk which has some events.
Within on of these events i need to display some data at the TextView.
The events are in an external class and i got them via some interfaces.
The interfaces iam implementing within the Activity.
I am using Handler and Message to set the text into the TextView within the implementation of the interface.
I would like to know if there is another way to set the text within the the interfaces except Handler and Message.

Here is that code:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView nameTextView;

    // some code

   
    // implementing interfaces of external class
    Service.ServiceEvents events = new Service.ServiceEvents() {
       
       @Override
       public void onSomeEvent(String name) {
           nameTextView.setText(name); // not working
           Message m = myHandler.obtainMessage(0, nameTextView);
           m.sendToTarget();
       }
       
       Handler myHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
          @Override
          public void handleMessage(Message message) {

            String s = message.obj.toString();

            nameTextView.setText(s);

          }
       };
    }

 } // end of activity
```

Is there another way to set the text in the TextView?
Please Help.

Comment: there is no harm to the sdk. u can continue

Comment: I am asking if there is another way to set the text into the TextView. Forget about the SDK.

Comment: When u want to send data from 1 activity or class to another, there is no choice but to use an interface.

Comment: Can you post an example of it as an answer how to make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What to use

---

You can do it by using an interface.

### How to implement

---

- Create a new `interface` and give it a name whatever u like.(Here it is `SampleInterface`).
- Add some void methods to like this

  ```
  void onSomeEvent(String name);
  ```
- Create a object of it in the class where you get the data from the sdk and add this listener in its constructor. Something like this

  ```
  public YourJavaClassName(SampleInterface sampleInterface) {
    this.sampleInterface= sampleInterface;
  }
  ```
- When you receive an update in the sdk, you can call it like this

  ```
  void onDataReceived(String name){// I don't know how you get the value from the sdk so I wrote this
      sampleInterface.onSomeEvent(name);
  }
  ```

You are done with implementing it in the sdk receiver class. Now you need to add to the main activity to receive and update data.

- Create the object of the class where you receive the data from the sdk.Like this

  ```
  MySDKReceiverClass mysdkreceiverclass;
  mysdkreceiverclass = new MySDKReceiverClass(this);
  ```
- Implement the interface in the activity and there you ge the values and you can set it in the textview.

###### Note: You need not add any runnable or handler or anything.Whenever there is a value change, the listener is called and the value is set.

Comment: thank you for help my friend :)

Comment: glad it helped u